# Restoring the android activity state to the state from where it begun

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making an application in which I want the application to come to a state in which it was, when was installed into the mobile, which includes deleting all the stored sharedpreference keys and sqllite data. Is it possible, if yes then how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!

```
   FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(classname.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        db.execSQL("delete from " + table.TABLE_NAME);
                        db.close();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.clear().commit();
```

Comment: It is the  class that you need to make that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. It has all the create and drop table queries.

Comment: Isn't there any "transformation of state" kind of solution?

Answer (score 0):

An event occurred when you want to start your application as new perform the following operations.

```
Flush out all sqlite data
Flush out all pref data
```

start your SplashActivity with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
```

it will clear all activity stack and you will access your App with starting phase.

Comment: Actually flushing manually each and every thing separately was not the problem. I wanted to know if something could be done which will negate everything done in the application so far and bring it into a newly born state. I hope you understand that.

Comment: I mean you want to carry out data with fresh App right?

Comment: Yes all the data except the data which is coded into the application, should be erased.